# Where is the inaccuracy of my arduino thermistor circuit coming from?

Tags: arduino-uno, electronics, temperature-sensor

[image]I've setup four thermistors and a known resistor in series and connected them to the 3.3V output (as I've heard it's cleaner than the 5V) of an Arduino Uno (with the 3.3V also connected to ARef to increase accuracy), with the four analog inputs testing the voltage drop across each thermistor to determine its resistance, and hence temperature.

But even with no change in the thermistor temperatures, the voltages I get from the arduino vary significantly. See below an example readout of the four arduino inputs (with thermistor temperatures/resistances same throughout):

230 424 634 849

212 412 597 819

241 415 611 857

204 413 654 845

The accuracy I come out with is around 5-10 degrees - way more than I expected. Why is this? And what can I do to get it down to less than one degree? Many thanks

UPDATE:
A MASSIVE THANKYOU to all those who helped me on this, particularly @NickGammon, @Talk2 and most of all @JRobert for the brilliantly clear and simple to follow circuit instructions to follow, all of which helped to thoroughly solve my problem! The sensor works great now, many thanks!!

Comment: Have you check your thermistor specs for their rated accuracy ? Also your 3.3v Vref how stable is it ? Maybe attach a schematic and thermistor p/n may help providing a better answer.

Comment: Perhaps if you post your code? And the thermistor model? Are those analog input readings? If so, a reading of around 200 is only 20% of the range of the ADC (which can go up to 1023) so any errors are going to be amplified by 5.

Comment: Hi Andre and Nick, thanks for your comments. The thermistors are ATC Semitec 104GT-2 Gt Thermistor 100k 3% - rated %3 - but I've checked them with a multimeter and they're not source of this error. They'll flicker a KOhm (about 1%) either side of their resistnace but will not vary more than that. Some of the values above change 15% between readings. The 3.3Vref I was told was better than the 5V, that's all I know. I can draw you a schematic but its a very simple circuit as described with no extra bells and whistles so far

Comment: I can also post my code if you want but I don't see how it would help as the values above are literally the analog values themselves as measured by the arduino (using ARef as well). The code simply takes the analog input values, and converts them into temperatures using the steinhart equation. It also takes an average but this doesn't really help.

Comment: Nick, good point about how the voltage of each thermistor is being described by only 20% of the 1023 range of the analog inputs - but if this were to blame wouldn't this mean the values varied less, rather than more as you can see above?

Comment: You did set `analogReference(EXTERNAL)` **before** connecting AREF to 3.3V, right?

Comment: Please do show a schematic - or at the very least a photograph of your setup.

Comment: Hi Edgar, what do you mean by 'before'? My setup code sets analogreference(EXTERNAL), before the loop code if that's what you mean. But the 3.3V and ARef pins are already physically connected before I plug the arduino into the laptop.

Comment: @Andre and Majenko please see picture above

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to connect the themistors individually, instead of all in series? Inaccuracies in one sensor, will influence the others. Also, since you can only read one analog pin at a time, the value of the previously read themistor could have changed, when reading the next. I think you are also losing some range, as you have to share the range between 4 readings.

Comment: @Gerben how do you mean individually? Do you mean have one arduino per thermistor?

Comment: No. You have wired it so that each reading will be influenced by the values from the other thermistors. Why not have each one wired with their own resistor (for the voltage divider)? In fact, why have four anyway? They are all adjacent aren't they?

Comment: *if this were to blame wouldn't this mean the values varied less, rather than more as you can see above?* - yes perhaps, but the calculated temperature will lose precision. You will be converting 0-200 into degrees when you could be converting 0-1023 into degrees.

Comment: What I would like you to do is remove the "thermistors in series" effect. Take a single thermistor, and your 100k resistor, and take some readings. ie. `+5V --- 100k --(A0)-- thermistor --- Gnd` - see if a) It gives the desired temperature; and b) Do they vary by such a large amount?

Comment: 1) My bad, as long as `analogReference(EXTERNAL)` is done before the first `analogRead()`, you are fine. 2) Now, I just did a small experiment. For lack of a suitable thermistor, I used an LDR with a 10 kΩ pullup. Out of 4399 readings, I only got 4 distinct values: 572 (11 times), 573 (1698 times), 574 (2599 times) and 575 (91 times). The RMS amplitude of the fluctuations was about 0.53 ADC steps. All this with the 5V reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using the voltage divider and measuring by parts? As @nickgammon points out, you are measuring only a 1/5 of full scale at each measurement, meaning your resolution is down by 5:1 over what the A/D is capable of. Also, the divider network comes to around 500KOhms. Work out the current through that and you get a very feeble <7 microAmps. The wires are antennas that could well be contributing noise at a significant fraction of that level.

Is there a reason for the divider circuit? Could you use a single thermistor from Vcc to Gnd plus a resistor in a 2-way divider? That will have the advantages of:

- Using (more of) the full range of A/D;
- Taking only one reading instead of several (and the several are necessarily skewed in time since you're multiplexing the one A/D);
- A larger current (ok, only 33 microAmps, but 5x better than before);
- Presumably less pickup into the network than with 5 leads. Keeping the measurement lead as short as possible may help, too.

Update:

Then you probably want a 2-component divider for each temperature you need to measure, paralleled between the power rails. I just guessed, not calculated, the resistances of R1, R3, R5, & R7. You'll want to estimate the maximum and minimum temperatures of interest in each channel and pick values that will give you the best ranges without drawing excessive currents when the thermistor values are low.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fX4nAD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: No I need four temperature sensors for purpose. Could using smaller resistance thermistors help?

Comment: I still think that by connecting the thermistors in series you are summing the errors. So if the first one has a 1% error (or some jitter) then that will vary the voltage being received by the second one, and so on. I'm testing with a thermistor and a 100k resistor (not your thermistor exactly) and I am seeing a couple of mV jitter (probably noise being picked up).

Answer (score 1):

Without exactly knowing part names, models and source code is difficult to tell what to expect. But a few techniques can be used to improve the stability of an analog reading. Here a few things you might want to consider:

1. Use INTERNAL vref of 1.1V, this is a very stable voltage reference
2. Use a stable/good quality series resistor, with little tolerance, like 1%
3. Add a 22pF capacitor, connecting the analog input to ground. This helps stabilizing the signal
4. Perform multiple consecutive readings, let's say 5 readings, and use the average. You might also want to remove the biggest and lowest values before averaging.

Comment: Hi Talk2, thanks very much for the suggestions. The parts are Arduino Uno SMD A000073 Board Rev3, ATC Semitec 104GT-2 Gt Thermistor 100k 3%, and Vishay CNS020 Series Radial Thin Film Resistor 100kΩ ±0.02% 0.5W ±10ppm/°C.

Comment: The values above are literally printouts of analog inputs (using Aref again), so the source code doesn't explain the variance in values there.

Comment: I do use an average in the main code, but it doesn't really help as the intial inputs are so variable.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by adding a 22pf capacitor between input and gnd? Do you mean wire the thermistors to the analog inputs and then from there to GND across the capacitor?

Comment: If I changed the 10 bit Uno for a 12 bit Due board, do you think that would improve the quality of the readouts?

Comment: or would it just increase the resolution, rather than the accuracy or precision of the analog readings above?

Comment: From 10bits to 12bits you only going to get more resolution. The Arduino analog ports are quite good for what you need. Why are you chain all the sensors? Have you tried with a single one? The capacitor needs to be between the Analog port and ground, so it works like a "buffer" to stabilize the voltage output from the voltage divider made of the Thermstor and the Resistor.

Answer (score 1):

I may be mistaking, but what you did is a voltage divisor where you read the voltage across resistors in series (your thermistors).

When resistors are in series as you know you add their value. So A4 is reading the value across TR1+TR2+TR3+TR4. A3 is reading the value across TR1+TR2+TR3 and so forth.

Comment: Yes Andre I had worked that out - my code takes this into account. By taking the differential between voltage readings all the resistance values can be worked out. But I don't think any of this is relevant unfortuately as the analog readings themselves, before even being processed by the code at all, are so instable as you can see.

Comment: You did look at this reference right :
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/AnalogReference